# Can't understand a step in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone explain how $2(x+h)^2$ becomes $2(x^2+2xh+h^2)$

What properties are used?

Comment: do you know $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all comes down to the distributive law:
$$
2(x+h)^2 = 
2[\color{red}{(x+h)}
\color{blue}{(x+h)}] 
= 2[
\color{red}x\color{blue}{(x+h)} 
+ \color{red}h\color{blue}{(x+h)}]\\ 
= 2[\color{red}x\color{blue}x + 
\color{red}x\color{blue}h + 
\color{red} h\color{blue}x + 
\color{red} h\color{blue}h]
= 2[x^2 + 2xh + h^2]
$$
You could reach the same conclusion using the [FOIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method) method.

Comment: Thank you. That makes it clearer.